# Angular Interpolation Error when formatting number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm fairly new to Angular and am probably missing something obvious but I have the following custom filter:

```
propertyApp.filter('telLink', function() {
return function(tel) {

    // To avoid interpolating error
    if(typeof(tel) != undefined) {

        // Remove any leading zeros
        if(tel.charAt(0) === '0') {
            tel = tel.substr(1);
        }

        tel = "44" + tel;

        // Remove any internal whiespace
        return tel.replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

});

When I use this in a view I get this:

```
Can't interpolate: tel:{{property.agent_phone | telLink}}
TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(typeof(tel) != undefined) {
```

just do

```
if (tel) {
```

This checks for "truthyness," and an undefined tel will not pass this test (the current code lets undefined values through)

js has lots of strange inconsistent behaviour.  Here's the top link on google for truthyness : http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: An even better way would be to use `angular.isDefined(tel)`. It does mostly the same thing but guarantees the value is suitable for angular to consume.